# In thymeleaf i want to break loop when my if condition is satisfied

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have this code in my html file and i want to break my thymeleaf loop when first time my if condition is satisfied.

My loop is here

```
<span  th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(${cart.orderItems})}" th:each="item : ${cart.orderItems}" 
            th:if="${item.parentOrderItem}==null and ${item.category} != null"   id="ie-print-help" class="ie-print-help"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using too many `${}` when they are not needed.

```
    <span th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(cart.orderItems)}" th:each="item : ${cart.orderItems}">
        <span th:if="${item.parentOrderItem ==null and item.category != null}"   id="ie-print-help" class="ie-print-help">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
         </span>
     </span>
```

Comment: You code is just a formatted version. how does it break the loop?